# Tradingview Pinescript - Comparing 2 securities, moving one +5 days in timeframe

Tags: pine-script

In comparing 2 securities, one of which I feel the price action leads the other by +5 days, so looking for help on how to frame this in Pinescript.

Knowledge is basic AF so keeping it KISS appreciated (crayons optional)

Answer (score 4):

This will plot a selectable ticker on your chart, on the left price scale.
You can also select the number of bars you want to shift.
Negative number for left shift, positive number for right shift.
You can also select what you want it to plot: `close` (default), `open`, `high`, `low`, etc...

```
//@version=4
study("SO", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

sym = input("NASDAQ:AAPL",  "Compare to ticker",    input.symbol)
lag = input(0,              "Shift number of bars", input.integer)
src = input(close,          "Plot source",          input.source)

sym_src = security(sym, timeframe.period, src)

plot(sym_src, "Lagged", color.yellow, offset=lag)
```

Example of `AAPL` compared to `MSFT`, shifted left 10 days.

[image]